# Library or framework to create custom Linq provider

Tags: .net, linq, custom-linq-providers

What libraries or frameworks to create custom Linq provider do you know?

How's you experience? Pros and cons? What's the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Re-linq (http://relinq.codeplex.com/). NHibernate uses it in its Linq provider in 3.0 version. We used it too in out project to simplify linq expressions for serializing. I think everyone, who wants to create Linq provider, should take a look on it. Also this [article](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2001564) by Ayende Rahien can be useful.

Comment: Re-linq seems to be mature and quite nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Linq Extender](http://mehfuzh.github.com/LinqExtender/). Personally I would prefer to code it by myself according to the needs for better performance, but takes more time. In any case, I would strongly suggest to start with [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

I created a project called [LinqToAnything](https://github.com/mcintyre321/LinqToAnything) for writing basic Linq providers without having to faff around with Expression Trees etc. You might find it useful if you are querying an API or SQL or something and just need filtering/paging/ordering.